# Preserve Android fragment data after calling Camera intent

Tags: android, save, fragment

I have Fragment which has edittext box , with text inside. Also a button to capture image. I have this code to capture image

```
     cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
       cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
       startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

The issue is when I take picture , or even cancel taking picture and get back to the main fragment, the Edittextbox data is empty.
Question : how to preserve data so that after get image from camera intent, all data into prevous fragment is kept.

Thanks.

Comment: Your process may be being terminated while the camera UI is in the foreground. So, use `onSaveInstanceState()` and the saved instance state `Bundle` passed into various fragment methods. Or, if you are using the Jetpack `ViewModel` system, use its `SavedStateHandle`.

Comment: I have tried to pass bundle to Camera intent  (cameraIntent.putExtra). with this , I can send data of different edittextboxes . It should be sent to Camera intent. But when I check the intent coming from Camera back to the frament, It does not contain these bundle extras

Comment: "I have tried to pass bundle to Camera intent (cameraIntent.putExtra). with this" -- OK, but, that is not what I suggested. I suggested saved instance state. See [this bit of documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states), [this bit of documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state), and [this documentation as well](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate).

Comment: I am checking and will feedback soon.  Thanks.. :)

Comment: saving instance is OK , but after getting camera image, the onCreate is not called upon camera intent is closed and return to fragment

Comment: Worked thanks.. for the links